# I want to create dynamic array with multiple dynamic value under each key PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have array like this i want to marge host array and ip array, i want to add specific IP address into unique host-name as a key.

```
[chns_host] => Array
     (
              [0] => ns1.dafhsdfhfhdkfd.com
              [1] => ns2.dafhsdfhfhdkfd.com
              [2] => ns1.dafhsdfhfhdkfd.com
              [3] => ns2.dafhsdfhfhdkfd.com
     )

     [chns_ip] => Array
     (
              [0] => 149.56.51.28
              [1] => 149.56.51.29
              [2] => 149.56.51.30
              [3] => 149.56.51.31
     )
```

I want to convert this array like

```
[ns1.dafhsdfhfhdkfd.com] => Array
     (
     [0] => 149.56.51.28
     [1] => 149.56.51.30
     )
[ns2.dafhsdfhfhdkfd.com] => Array
     (
     [0] => 149.56.51.29
     [1] => 149.56.51.31
     )
```

Ip will need to go under specific key hostname.

Comment: You must iterate through this 2 arrays and make checks with network functions like [dns_get_record()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php) and create a new array that becomes your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by this way: (works only if the # of rows in hosts equal to # of rows in ips)

```
$array = <yourArray>;
$newArray = array();

foreach($array['chns_host'] as $id => value){
    $newArray[$value][] = $array['cnhs_ip'][$id];
}

var_dump($newArray);
```